# Использование доктайпа HTML5 со старой структурой верстки

Tags: html, вёрстка, html5

Можно ли использовать в верстке доктайп html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`, но при этом не использовать никаких других элементов html5 (типа `<header>, <section>, <article>, <footer>` и т.д.), а верстать со старой структурой (`<div id="header">, <div id="content">, <div id="footer">` и т.д.). Есть ли какие-то особенности при верстке с таким доктайпом? Могут ли возникнуть какие-нибудь проблемы? Какие он дает преимущества?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. Никаких проблем. Простота и лёгкость запоминания.

Comment: ясно, спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно, доктайпы, если память не изменяет, нужны для валидаций и + что в IE верстка будет более менее схожа с остальными, от верстки зависит.

Comment: под ие верстку, точнее говоря, стили, в любом случае нужно корректировать.

Comment: Да конечно , но с использованием Доктайпов , это будет чуть проще )